# Symfony2 Doctrine - WHERE IN as pair

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, where-in

Basically I want to make a query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`c1`,`c2`) in (('a','b'),('c','d'))
```

I tried a few things but I couldn't find any advice how to achieve that. I tried some stuff like that:

```
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $columns[] = "(" . $pair->getc1() . "," . $pair->getc2() . ")";
}

$query = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Combinations')->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->select()
                ->where('(c.c1,c.c2) in (:pairs)')
                ->setParameter('pairs', $columns)
                ->getQuery();
```

This obviously didn't work for me, do you have any idea how to use multiple values in `where in` statements?

**EDIT:**

I managed to do this shitty way. I doubt it's the best way and I still think there should be a better solution so I would love to see it.

```
$query = $this->entityManager
    ->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Combinations')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select();

$expr = $query->expr();

$i = 1;
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $query = $query->orWhere($expr->andX($expr->eq('c.c1', ':c1' . $i), $expr->eq('c.c2', ':c2' . $i)))
            ->setParameter('c1' . $i, $pair->getc1())
            ->setParameter('c2' . $i, $pair->getc2()) 
    ;

    $i++;
}

$query = $query->getQuery();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you just cannot have `WHERE (col1, col2)` in Doctrine... However, I can imagine an extension that would be a custom function in Doctrine. It could be something like `PAIRS((col1, col2), (val1_1, val2_1), (val1_2, val2_2), (val1_N, val2_N))` that would be finally turned to normal raw sql. The thing is that it would be tricky to validate the input.

Comment: damn it :( thanks for info, at least I won't have to look for this any further

Comment: Please check my answer, maybe it can somehow work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I found some solution, which you will definitely not like, but it works somehow.

There are three problems basically:
1. You cannot have WHERE (col1, col2) in DOCTRINE
2. You cannot pass array of arrays as a parameter (to build pairs)
3. You cannot have an where expression without a comparison.

But please check my workaround.

Extension class:

```
/*
 * This file is part of the Acme package.
 *
 * (c) Denis V.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Query;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

/**
 * Class Pairs
 *
 * @author Denis V.
 *
 * @package Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Query
 */
class Pairs extends FunctionNode
{
    public $cols = array();
    public $pathExp = array();

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();

        // first Path Expression is mandatory
        $this->pathExp = array();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->cols[] = $parser->SingleValuedPathExpression();
        while ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_COMMA)) {
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
            $this->cols[] = $parser->SingleValuedPathExpression();
        }
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);

        $j = 1;
        while ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_COMMA)) {
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
            $this->pathExp[$j] = array($parser->StringPrimary());
            while ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_COMMA)) {
                $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
                $this->pathExp[$j][] = $parser->StringPrimary();
            }

            // commented out as it should be possible to accept array parameters
            //if (count($this->cols) != count($this->pathExp[$j])) {
            //    $parser->semanticalError('Number of columns must be the same as number of compared values');
            //}

            $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
            $j++;
        }

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        $fields = array();
        foreach ($this->cols as $col) {
            $fields[] = $col->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        }

        $result = sprintf('(%s)', implode(', ', $fields));

        $result .= ' IN ';

        $expr = array();
        foreach ($this->pathExp as $pathExp) {
            $fields = array();
            foreach ($pathExp as $item) {
                $fields[] = $item->dispatch($sqlWalker);
            }
            $expr[] = sprintf('(%s)', implode(', ', $fields));
        }

        $result .= sprintf('(%s)', implode(', ', $expr));

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Now you can do the following (assuming, you are in the entity repository):

```
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('PAIRS((c.c1, c.c2), (:pair)) != \'dummy\'')
        ->setParameter('pair', array('val1', 'val2'));
    $q = $qb->getQuery();

    return $q;
```

As you may notice there is `!= 'dummy'` in the code. This is because you cannot pass a WHERE expression without comparison. I checked, it actually works this way with MySQL. But you may remove it using custom SqlWalker.

To pass more pairs, you will need to use cycles as you cannot pass array of arrays as a single parameter.

Something like this:

```
$dqlParts = array();
foreach ($pairs as $i => $pair) {
    $dqlParts[] = sprintf('(?%d)', $i);
    $qb->setParameter($i, $pair);
}
$dqlPartsStr = implode(', ', $dqlParts);
```

And then use this $dqlPartsStr in your DQL (NB: the last code block is written on StackOverflow without testing).

I know, this looks more like a hack, but this is all you can do within Doctrine2. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: even though it's not exactly what I was looking for I assign the points to you as you did the most research, thanks.

Comment: @KeluThatsall thank you for the bounty. As of not exactly what you were looking for, well, it seems that the only difference is this trick with 'dummy', otherwise the DQL is converted to pretty good paired SQL: `WHERE (col1, col2) IN (('val1.1', 'val2.2'), ('val.2', 'val2.2'), ('val1.N', 'val2.N'))` that's just compared to 'dummy' (which has no side effect). And like I mentioned, this 'dummy' string can be easily removed by custom SqlWalker. Anyway, again thanks for the bounty ;)

Comment: aye, but tbh I wanted to be able to use different numbers of parameters, not only pairs :P I hoped there is a solution built into the doctrine already, but I just didn't find it. In the end I built this query without even using QueryBuilder - not worth it imo ;)

Comment: @KeluThatsall I see, but in fact my solution is not limited to pairs ;) `Pairs` function node is first parsing for columns until the first closing parenthesis: `PAIRS((col1, col2, ..., colN)`, and then it parses values: `,('val1.1','val.2', ..., 'val1.N'), ... ('valM.1', 'valM.2', ..., 'valM.N'))`, so, as you can see, it's not limited this way.

Comment: ah true, to be honest i didn't test it very well, thanks for that. But as I said, I will be using standard SQL prepared statements, cuz I think it's too much trouble to use those QueryBuilders with some more complicated queries ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be tried:

```
$separator = '|||';
$columns = [];
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $columns[] = $pair->getc1() . $separator . $pair->getc2();
}
$query = $this
    ->entityManager
    ->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Combinations')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select()
    ->where("CONCAT_WS('" . $separator . "', c.c1, c.c2) in (:pairs)")
    ->setParameter('pairs', $columns)
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Did you check it, or just guessing?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried toArray()?

Like this:

```
->select()
->where('(c.c1,c.c2) in (:pairs)')
->setParameter('pairs', $columns->toArray())
->getQuery();
```

Comment: How would that work? `$columns` is an array already, it hasn't got any methods, it's not an object